# asp.net cache key cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I am running asp.net application. In one functions, I try to add a cache for later use. However, the log always say that the cache key is not found. It seems the cache key is not added. At first loading of the page, when it says "cannot find", it's normal. Then I reload the page, it should find the the cache key but it still says the cache key is not found. What is wrong with my code? Here is my code

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;
public class ReportManager
{
    protected static MemoryCache CACHE = new MemoryCache("Report_Cache");

    public static DataSet KPISummaryReport(int companyID, int fromYear, int fromMonth, int toYear, int toMonth, string locationIDs, bool hideIfNoValue, string lang)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        string requestUri = string.Format("Report/KPISummaryReport/?companyID={0}&fromYear={1}&fromMonth={2}&toYear={3}&toMonth={4}&locationIDs={5}&hideIfNoValue={6}&fmt=xml&lang={7}"
            , companyID, fromYear, fromMonth, toYear, toMonth, locationIDs, hideIfNoValue, lang);
        DataSet ds = null; 

        string cacheKey = "kpi_" + companyID + "_" + fromYear + "_" + fromMonth + "_" + toYear + "_" + toMonth + "_" + locationIDs;

        ds = CACHE.Get(cacheKey) as DataSet;

        if (ds != null)
        {
            Logger.Log(string.Format("Found the report dataset cache key {0}",cacheKey));
            return ds;                    
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Log(string.Format("Cannot find the report dataset cache key {0}",cacheKey));
            ds = Util.GetData(_sustainabilityServiceURL, requestUri, out result);
            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60d) };
            CACHE.Add(cacheKey, ds, policy);
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually debugged the application and verified that the item is being added to the cache? Try putting a log in catch block, just to be sure.

Comment: logged. The cache is added successfully. No error happened in catch block.

Comment: What do you get when you call "getCount" method on the cache? Try logging that after adding to the cache and before reading from it.

Comment: After adding to it. The count is 1. Before reading it, it is 0.

Comment: Could "as DataSet" be the reason?

Comment: But when GetCount of the CACHE. The count is 0. Why the cache count become zero?